CoPilot is temporarily unreachable after upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 17.11.2
Copilot stopped working after upgrading from Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise edition version 17.10.x to version 17.11.2. The message:

Copilot is temporarily unreachable

is shown when hovering over the Copilot icon as seen below.

I am working with company notebook behind proxy and VPN in the home office. I am very sure that nothing changed in my environment other than the VS upgrade
I followed the instructions here Troubleshooting Page to trouble shoot the issue, unfortunately without success. My Github Copilot account is valid and github endpoints are reachable. Even readding my github account didn't solve the problem

By coincidence I discovered that by opening Copilot chat window the status of Copilot immediately changed to green

